# Why are my em margins not computing correct?

Tags: css, pixel, font-size

I have a some problem with em units.

my base em unit is 16px

```
body {
    font-size:16px;
}
```

I try to give 30px margin-top to my h4 element, so 30px is equal to 1.87em,

```
h4 {
    font-size:1.875em;
    line-height: initial;               
    margin-top: 1.87em;
}
```

but when I look from web inspector computed section:

```
margin-top:56.1px;
```

is computed.

When I use `px` instead of `em`, like `margin-top:30px;`, everything is normal.

Why is this happening?

Comment: An `em` on a `h4` is equal to the font size of the `h4`, not the base font size. You probably meant `rem`.

Comment: no i meant em, i just didn't now , em on a h4 is equal to the font size of the h4

Comment: em worked in base font. I think your base h4 font size is higher.

Comment: i give based font-size to body, and think everything calculating over on this.

Comment: @tamilselvan Yes, the OP's data clearly shows that the h4 has a font size of 30px.

Comment: @user3348410 Then use `rem` like I said instead of `em`. That's what `rem`s are for. You should assign a font size to the `html` though, not the `body`.

Comment: @user3348410 Please update your code.

Comment: @tamil selvan i updated my code, i just confused now. my base font-size is not on body ?. so if i will give margin to h4, here em will calculating on h4 font-size?

Comment: @user3348410 Yes, `1em` is equal to the font size of the element. Not the font size of some other element. Except when you are setting the `font-size` property itself, then it's equal to the font size of the parent.

Comment: Yes. @MrLister Asked correct.

Comment: so, then i need now just give to html based font-size, and use the rems everywhere? i can give an example to html based font-size:16px and use this with rem on other elements like margin padding. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you shouldn't calculate em to pixels, but I understand it helps you to understand what you are doing. So ontopic....

You are defining a **base size** on your body `16px`

You define a font-size for you h4, `1.875em` which means: `1.875 x 16 = 30px`.
These `30px` are now the **base size** for your h4.

Meaning, the margin-top that you define on your h4 is actually `1.87 x 30 = 56.1px`

So if you want a '30px margin', use `margin-top: 1em` on your h4.

Hope it makes sense....

---

As already commented by Mr. Lister, as alternative you could use `rem` instead of `em`

Comment: i understood, if giving to element font-size different from the base font-size my 1em value is changing for this element. , if i'll give to my h4 element font-size base font-size like 16px(1em) everything was be okey.

Comment: That is correct. The use of `em` forces a different mindset :)